# Add DragScroll to slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

¡Hello! I have a slider of 3 sections, which works automatic and onlick, everything is fine but i want to add a dragscroll for mobile, but i don't have a clue of where to start, heres the code

```js
//almacenar slider en una variable
var slider = $('#slider');
//almacenar botones
var siguiente = $('#btn-next');
var anterior = $('#btn-prev');

//mover ultima imagen al primer lugar
$('#slider section:last').insertBefore('#slider section:first');
//mostrar la primera imagen con margen de -100%
slider.css('margin-left', '-'+100+'%');

function moverD() {
 slider.animate({marginLeft:'-'+200+'%'}, 700, function(){
  $('#slider section:first').insertAfter('#slider section:last');
  slider.css('margin-left', '-'+100+'%');
 });
}

function moverI() {
 slider.animate({marginLeft:0}, 700, function(){
  $('#slider section:last').insertBefore('#slider section:first');
  slider.css('margin-left', '-'+100+'%');
 });
}

function autoplay() {
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        moverD();
    }, 5000);
}

siguiente.on('click',function() {
    moverD();
    clearInterval(interval);
    autoplay();
});

anterior.on('click',function() {
    moverI();
    clearInterval(interval);
    autoplay();
});


autoplay();
```

```css
#principal{
 position: relative;
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-bottom: 6px solid #80d443;
 border-top: 6px solid #80d443;
}
#btn-prev, #btn-next{
 position: absolute;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px black;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: white;
 font-size: 30px;
 z-index: 80;
 top: 50%;
 font-weight: bold;
}
#btn-prev{
 left: 1%;
}
#btn-next{
 right: 1%;
}
#slider{ 
 display: flex;
 width: 900px;
 height: 300px;
}
section{
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
#diseño{
background: blue;
}
#solucion{
background: red;
}
#entrenamiento{
background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="content" id="principal">
  <section class="slider" id="slider">
    <section id="diseño">
    </section>
    <section id="solucion">
    </section>
    <section id="entrenamiento">
    </section>
  </section>
  <div id="btn-prev" class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true" data-stellar-ratio="1"><</div>
  <div id="btn-next" class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true" data-stellar-ratio="1">></div>
</section>
```

Any example or hint would be useful, Thanks in advance :D

I tried something like this and there i stopped

```js
$(function() {
    var slides = $('#slider section').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider').width();
    var min = 0;
    var max = -((slides - 1) * slideWidth);

    $("#slider").width(slides*slideWidth).draggable({
        axis: 'x',
        drag: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.position.left > min) ui.position.left = min;
            if (ui.position.left < max) ui.position.left = max;
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT:

I manage to make it work the drag function, but i'm having a lot of problems, here you can see the DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/visiond/9j3jLann/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding a second answer in case either option suits the OP better or those in the future.

This is using jquery and slick.js

**HTML**

```
<section class="slider">
    <div><img src="http://placeholder.of.today/300x300/12ec14/1844d"></div>
    <div ><img src="http://placeholder.of.today/300x300/ff0000/1844d"></div>
      <div ><img src="http://placeholder.of.today/300x300/0095ff/1844d"></div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.slider {
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.slick-slide {
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

    img { display: inline-block; }
}

.slick-prev:before, 
.slick-next:before {
    color: black;    
}

.slick-prev, .slick-next {
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
  z-index: 3;
}
.slick-next {
    right: 5px;
}
.slick-prev {
    left: 5px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".slider").slick({

    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
    customPaging : function(slider, i) {
    },

    responsive: [{ 
        breakpoint: 500,
        settings: {
            dots: false,
            arrows: false,
            infinite: false,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1
        } 
    }]
});
```

DEMO on Codepen.
https://codepen.io/norcaljohnny/pen/NbpPvL

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.

```
$(function() {
    var slides = $('#slider ul').children().length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider').width();
    var min = 0;
    var max = -((slides - 1) * slideWidth);

    $("#slider ul").width(slides*slideWidth).draggable({
        axis: 'x',
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.position.left > min) ui.position.left = min;
            if (ui.position.left < max) ui.position.left = max;
        }
    });
});
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/k71jugLk/

Comment: i'm having various problems with that code, here's the demo https://jsfiddle.net/visiond/9j3jLann/8/

Comment: I will look at it shortly had stepped out for a bit. I did notice some minor errors likes extra closing statements and some that were not there.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/visiond/9j3jLann/9/ Also, this works different in my than in the demo, so weird.

Comment: @AlexanderPulido - Sorry for the delay. I see you did not load fontawesome css and that is why you needed to add the arrows < > and this is caused errors. I removed the arrows, loaded FA and let the arrows load that way and loaded JSUI properly. See https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/9j3jLann/13/

Comment: The demo sites do not always work properly, it is good to use it in a working test environment. Please see the 2nd answer I also posted as it may be a lot easier for this and extended use.

Comment: It's not working, also, the demo work just like in my website. Look at the demo, drag one panel to the left, wait the auto animation, try to drag back, repeat process, eventualy you gonna be watching a white background. Also you cannot drag back when the animation activates. I think is the way i did it, the margin reescribe the margin defined in the drag function. I probably have two ways of doing it, 1.- make the slider like a sucession of "drags" instead of margins, or add the drag to the content and some way of restart the margin everytime the margin-animation activates

Comment: The second solution is awesome, it's exactly what i was looking for (because i wanted to add a draggable option to my original code), but it works, so y check it as correct answer. Thanks a lot mate :)

Comment: @AlexanderPulido Hey glad it worked out :) Its a good solution and no errors at all compared to the original answer. Cheers :)l